# Is it possible to change the value of an object using an indirect call in a different class than that in which it was instantiated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I am creating a custom table-view cell generator and I want to pass in a reference to an  Object created in a base class which will be mutated in a separate VC while the originating object class will reflect these changes:

```
//MutableTableViewObjects.h
@interface MutableTableViewObjects : NSObject
@property (retain, atomic) NSDate *startDate;

//MutableTableViewObjects.m

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

then I want a call in a separate view controller to change the value of startDate

```
self.objectClass = [[MutableTableViewObjects alloc] init];
DateOptionCellInput *startDateCell = [[DateOptionCellInput alloc] initDateInputForObject:self.objectClass.startDate withDefault:[NSDate date] withTitle:@"start date" inSection:@"Dates"];
```

From here I want startDateCell to modify the value of startDate and have self.objectClass.startDate reflect the changes happening to its value in other classes/threads

Is this even possible or should I seriously reconsider the architecture?

Currently the value changes in the VC but it is never updated in the base object class. Is there some property parameters I can pass in to allow this?

edit: here is how date cell will

```
@interface BaseOptionCellInput : NSObject

@property (atomic)  NSObject*  observedObject;

- (id) initType:(NSString*) optionType withTitle:(NSString*) titleString inSection:(NSString*) sectionHeaderString {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
           self.title = titleString;
        self.sectionHeader = sectionHeaderString;
        self.identifier = optionType;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setManagedObject:(NSObject*) managedObject withDefaultValue:(NSObject*) defaultvalue {
    self.observedObject = managedObject;
    self.defaultValue = defaultvalue;
}


- (void) updateContextWithValue:(NSObject*) newValue {
    if ([self.observedObject class] == [newValue class]) {
               self.observedObject = newValue;
    }
}
```

and then DateCell is a subclass of BaseCell and calls updateContextWithValue from a delegate method triggered in the VC.

I know I can accomplish this if I used a dictionary to pass the values of objects back and forth but I was hoping it was possible just passing a pointer to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine in initDateInputForObject function you are just using the value from the passed in object and assigning it to startDateCell's member variables.

What you want to do is probably keep a pointer to the MutableTableViewObjects object so you can directly modify the date value in there.

If you can add the code for MutableTableViewObjects I can elaborate with better clarity rather than shoot arrows in the dark :)

But hopefully you get the idea of what I am saying. Point being that no where in your code the orig MutableTableViewObjects object values are being updated..  Just because you used it to initialize another object doesn't mean it will stay updated when you change second object.

EDIT:

Lets say I have an class A with NSDate*
A.h

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property  NSDate *startDate;
}
```

with A.m

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now there is a class B as follows that contains an object of A.

B.h
    @interface B : UITableViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) A *aObject;
    @end

and B.m

```
- (void) some function {
    self.aObject = [[A alloc] init];
}
```

Now if you change self.aObject.startDate, you should be able to change the value of data in A directly.

If its not working as expected, tell me exactly what it is and where it is happening
thx

Comment: This is what I'd like to accomplish. I posted the other classes to maybe explain it better. I can also post the whole project on github if that would help

Comment: where is initDateInputForObject? I don't see any code in the BaseCell or DateCell setting the date values..  I am not sure I understand.. the code is in patches.. sorry

Comment: I pushed the entire project to git hub. I got it working using core data (which I knew I could do already) but I would still like to pass the objects to be mutated as pointers so that they can be assigned new values without knowing the name or type of the object. 

[gitHub repo](https://github.com/TheoBrown/MutatableTableViewController)

Comment: Core data is a storage mechanism and a way to share data across classes and between client and server but you don't need to do what you are trying to do. your question is not clear to me. I would advise that you update the question with only the problem code. The object that you expected to change after which function call. Looking at a large project like this without knowing the relevant classes is a waste of time for me. I am updating the answer with some more details